# Why can I import mako and not mako.Template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mako

I am trying to use Mako with my Twisted webserver in Python 3. I have a virtual environment with Mako installed (via pip). I am able to import the Mako package, but not the Template class. Here is the shell output from successfully importing the mako module, and then failing to import its Template class:

```
>>> import mako 
>>> from mako import Template
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Template'
```

Checking the module in site-packages reveals that there is indeed a template.py script with a Template class inside of it, so it's not missing from the install.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Template` is defined in `mako.template`

Thus you should use:

```
from mako.template import Template
```

Comment: Ah, what a fundamental error on my part! I'm still getting the hang of Python. Thank you for the speedy response, I'm glad such a simple mistake did not have to cost me much time in getting it solved.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote the answer if it was helpful.